# Redis doesn't start as a service inside a docker container

Tags: docker, redis, docker-swarm

I am pretty new to docker, so I followed their official tutorial and tried a "shortcut" applicable to my work projects. I have the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: my_image
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
    ports:
      - "4000:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - "/home/docker/data:/data"
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

my_image is a simple flask app that starts Flask and Redis and then prints number of visits:

```
from flask import Flask
from redis import Redis, RedisError
import os
import socket

# Connect to Redis
redis = Redis(host="redis", db=0, socket_connect_timeout=2, socket_timeout=2)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    try:
        visits = redis.incr("counter")
    except RedisError:
        visits = "<i>cannot connect to Redis, counter disabled</i>"

    html = "<h3>Hello {name}!</h3>" \
           "<b>Hostname:</b> {hostname}<br/>" \
           "<b>Visits:</b> {visits}"
    return html.format(name=os.getenv("NAME", "world"), hostname=socket.gethostname(), visits=visits)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

See [Dockerfile here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#define-a-container-with-dockerfile)

When I start a swarm like this:

```
sudo docker swarm init --advertise-addr <ip>
sudo docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml flask_with_redis
```

The `my_image` image starts fine and I can see it running on 127.0.0.1:4000, but Redis never starts.
I suspect that there is something wrong with my `docker-compose.yml`, particularly with the `redis` service because `my_image` runs fine.
Also Redis and Flask are definitely added to the `my_image` by running `requirements.py`.
Did anyone experience something similar? Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help Prathis and Bret Fisher.
It turns out that the solution is simpler: I just had to 'stick' to Docker tutorial and simply leave

```
placement:
   constraints: [node.role == manager]
```

So the full (working) docker-compile.yml looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: my_image
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
    ports:
      - "4000:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

This container runs Redis fine

Answer (score 0):

Your compose looks right, and your flask app service/image has nothing to do with the redis image starting up as a successful service.

1. What does `docker stack ps flask_with_redis` and `docker service logs flask_with_redis_redis` say?
2. I recommend watching `docker events` while you deploy the stack and see what it's trying to do with the redis service.

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me, I have executed the same with very little bit of changes to the docker-compose file like add the my_image image to the private registry and deploy-mode as global for redis as i am executing the swarm mode (1 manager 2 worker nodes). Please find the below steps.

Create a local registry with the below command.

```
docker service create registry --name registry --publish published=5003,target=5000 registry:2
```

update the image and build tag as mentioned below. Also update the deploy-mode as global for redis.

Note: If you are running on docker swarm make sure you have path /home/docker/data created on all the nodes.

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: 127.0.0.1:5003/my_image:latest
    build: .
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
    ports:
      - "4000:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
  redis:
    image: redis
    deploy:
      mode: global
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - "/home/docker/data:/data"
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Execute the below commands where all your artifacts (Dockerfile,docker-compose.yml,requirements.txt app.py) exists.

Run the below command to build the images.

```
docker-compose up -d
```

run the below command to delete the containers.

```
docker-compose down
```

run the below command to push the created the my_image image to the private registry.

```
docker-compose push
```

run the below command to create the stack with the same compose file.

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml redisapp
```

Screen shots for your ref.

[image: Deployed services in the docker swarm]

[image: Able to access from my local machine, docker swarm exit in the azure cloud.]

Hope it helps you, Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

I my case, it wasn't working because, for some reason, I had omitted `networks: - webnet` from `docker-compose.yml`. My understanding is that this tell the service to use the same network the others are using and that's how 'host=redis' in the python code is correctly resolved to the redis server.